# Is Apples goto-bug possible in Kotlin if-statement without braces?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinc

Imagine in Kotlin:

```
if (this) doThis()
else if(that) doThat()
else doWhatEver()
```

I've read using braces always ([see Apples goto fail](https://embeddedgurus.com/barr-code/2014/03/apples-gotofail-ssl-security-bug-was-easily-preventable/))!

> Rule 1.3.a
>
> Braces shall always surround the blocks of code (a.k.a., compound
>   statements), following if, else, switch, while, do, and for
>   statements; single statements and empty statements following these
>   keywords shall also always be surrounded by braces.

How does the Kotlin compiler handle the lack of braces in the above code? I thought Kotlin might be intelligent enough to avoid failures on that?

Comment: That's C then. Kotlin compiler is completely different. To answer why Kotlin don't fail to that thing will probably take a full semester of compilers lecture, some years of field experience and digging into kotlin's sources. I'm now voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Maybe this would be a silly question, or I didn't understand your question well, but still: Why don't you try yourself? If I understood the question, you could just run the code and put some `println()`s there to see what it does.

Comment: @glee8e "Kotlin compiler is completely different. To answer why Kotlin don't fail to that thing" Yeah, I was hoping for a link to a tech article regarding that :D ..

Answer (score 1):

The example you give is not ambiguous; it could only have one reasonable meaning.  And it's rather different from the issue you link to (which doesn't involve `else` clauses at all.)  So I'm not sure what you're asking.

Kotlin is similar to most C-like languages in how it interprets `if` (and `else`).  So strictly speaking, an error of that type is still possible.  But Kotlin has two features which can reduce the risk of such problems.

First is that, unlike C and Java and similar languages, `if` can be used as an expression (returning a value).  When used this way, the compiler ensure that every branch returns a value; this will usually result in a compiler error if there's any confusion around multiple branches.

Second is the `when` structure, which functions like the C/Java `switch` statement, but avoids fall-through and hence the need for `break`s; it can also be used as an expression, enforcing a single path through and a single return value.

So in Kotlin, the linked code would best have been written with a `when`, which would have been simpler as well as preventing that type of error.

Ultimately, I don't think it's really comparable, though.  The linked code is low-level C, which has very different practices and restrictions from general application code.  In particular, the use of `goto` for error clean-up is inherently error-prone.  And if they'd used `else` branches properly, it would have made the code rather clearer as well as preventing this error.

It's possible to write bad code in any language if you're determined enough!  A good language is one which makes it easier to write good code, and harder to write bad code.  (And I think Kotlin scores pretty well in that respect.)